# how to delete an app that says "books" in the software catalog via terminal?

Tags: apt

So I'm trying to automate delete unneeded apps on my setup.

Some of it are straightforward since the description list the package name. But there's 1 app (Books) where I cannot find the package name.

I've tried

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep book
dpkg --get-selections | grep read
```

using "book" as keyword, it gave me several packages that starts with "libebook" but when I tried deleting it, it want to delete a whole heap of stuff like not related to e-books.

Any ideas on how to easily associate apps in the Software catalog with a package name?

Thanks

Comment: I didn't get it, you don't know the command? or you don't know the package name? if you know one of them let me know.

Comment: Use `dpkg -l *book* | grep ii` to find the title that you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like this may be the package you're describing.

[image: Screenshot from 2017-06-09 08-22-59.png]

The package name is `gnome-documents`, and you can check to see if it is installed on your system by running `dpkg -l | grep 'gnome-documents'` in a terminal.

Note that the screenshot is taken from the older Ubuntu Software Center which can be installed with `sudo apt install software-center`, not to be confused with the newer Ubuntu Software which is the `ubuntu-software` package. I like the older Ubuntu Software Center better for a number of reasons, one of them being that it shows the name of the package when you click the <kbd>More Info</kbd> button.

Answer (score 1):

The name and details seen there are from appstream's database, so you can try searching there:

```
$ appstreamcli search books
Identifier: org.gnome.Books.desktop [desktop-application]
Name: Books
Summary: An e-book manager application for GNOME
Package: gnome-documents
Homepage: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Books
Icon: gnome-documents_org.gnome.Books.png
---
Identifier: FBReader.desktop [desktop-application]
Name: E-book reader
Summary: FBReader E-book reader
...
```

The first entry here has the exact name "Books", and the homepage given here is the same site that the <kbd>Website</kbd> button on Ubuntu Software links to.

You can then remove the package using `appstreamcli` and the identifier `org.gnome.Books.desktop`:

```
$ appstreamcli remove org.gnome.Books.desktop
Resolving                     [=========================]         
Testing changes               [=========================]         
Finished                      [                         ] (0%)  
The following packages have to be removed:
 gnome-documents-3.28.0-1.amd64 Document manager for GNOME
Proceed with changes? [N/y] y

                              [=========================]         
Removing                      [=========================]         
Waiting for authentication    [=========================]         
Loading cache                 [=========================]         
Running                       [=========================]         
Removing packages             [=========================]         
Installing packages           [=========================]         
Finished                      [=========================]
```

Or use `apt`/`apt-get` and the package name `gnome-documents`.